# What's the name for images like these?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, website-design, color

I'm trying to figure out the name for, or a collection of, the kinds of images that "fade-into" a solid color.

For example, twitter has this image:

[image: https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/images/themes/theme1/bg.png]

This allows them to add a background image that doesn't have a large file size, and then they set the background color of the website to be the color of the bottom of the image.

The end result makes it look as if the entire page is an image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuRgy.png]

Does anyone know if a name exists for images like this that "fade-into" a color or if there's a place where these kinds of images are posted?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no specific name for this.

Answer (score 2):

It is tiled horizontally, which in the 3D gaming world is called a 'tilable texture' (tilable background in web terms I guess). The 'make the bottom a flat color so it matches the color you set in CSS' part is just practicality, I don't think it has a label.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a specific name. If anything, it may be considers a background tile. However, that refers much more to the use than the style.

These types of images are **always** custom created to match the web design. You would have a very hard time searching for background images which reflect a transition to a specific color.

Answer (score 1):

Background image or tile in the web design world. Having the background fade to a similar or matching background is just general practice, there's no name for that.